# Using SMS to register

Tags: registration, sms

How to make SMS registration easier?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Send SMS with any simple text ("reg") to the service number.
2. Fill the registration form (while service generates and sends answer).
3. Enter the number from SMS answer.
4. Submit.

Using cell phone or cell to cell money transfer image on the banner could visually explain technology behind your system and necessity of sharing cell number which is a bit private info.

Comment: thanks this is first time i post a question and am getting very great answers  thank am liking being here

Comment: the system works " reg "your email" ..... i cant change there system

Comment: It's more complex task to enter text on mobile comparing to desktop. So this could be a barrier to your customers. User testing and time measurement could be convincing enough to your boss. I currently have the situation when the programmers are lazy and pull the boss to their side while I try to convince him to be more user friendly. They lost users and I going to explain to boss worth of changes comparing to lost of customers.